# @types/typeahead use in Angular 4 cli project

Tags: angular, typeahead.js, typeahead

I am trying to use @types/typeahead in my angular cli project. I installed typehead.js type definition using following command.

```
npm install --save @types/typeahead
```

And did the following on OnInit() method of the component.

```
const suggestions = [{
      value: 'string1'
    }, {
      value: 'string2'
    }, {
      value: 'string3'
    }, {
      value: 'string4'
    }, {
      value: 'string5'
    }];

      let bloodhoundSuggestions = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        sufficient: 3,
        local: this.suggestions


    });
```

But it always gives following error.

```
Can not find name 'Bloodhound'
```

I added following files to angular-cli.json file too.

```
"assets/js/bloodhound.min.js",
"assets/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"
```

I have installed jQuery too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare `Bloodhound` in the typescript files where you want to use it

```
// under your imports in component.ts
declare const Bloodhound;
```

Now the typescript compiler shouldn't throw that error